# Change property class type in private implementation

Tags: objective-c

I have a class on iOS which has a `UIView` property that other objects are able to read. For the sake of my internal implementation of this class, I want this view to be a custom subclass of `UIView`, but there is no need for the clients of this class to be aware of that. To them, this property should and will behave just like any other `UIView`.

Ideally what I want is something like this.

MyViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *aView;
```

MyViewController.m:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CustomView *aView;
```

The compiler allows me to do this, but it doesn't actually understand what I want to do. It won't allow to message `.aView` as a `CustomView` object, it just lets me message it as a regular `UIView` object.

A workaround I have at the moment is to do this.

```
CustomView *newView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[newView customViewMessage];
self.aView = newView;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred approach is to give the private property a different name.  I then implement the getter for the public property and return the internal property's instance variable.

Example:

**Class.h**

```
@interface Class : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *aView

@end
```

**Class.m**

```
@interface Class ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomView *cView;

@end

@implementation

- (UIView *)aView {
    return _cView;
}

@end
```

Comment: Of course! I actually now remember doing this ages ago...can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a view controller this is how you'd do it.

**Step one.**

Add a private property, for example

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CustomView *customView;
```

And override the getter to return the view.

```
-(CustomView *)customView{ return (id)self.view; }
```

This way you can use that property to call methods specific to your class without having to cast it every time, and any other objects can interface with your view controller's view in the same way they would with any other view controller.

**Step 2**

Since you are using a view controller there are two options:

1. You are instantiating the vc from a storyboard

In this case, you can select the view in Interface Builder and set it to a custom class. Done.

2. You are instantiating the VC from code

In that case, you have to override your view controller's `loadView` method and create your view in there:

```
-(void)loadView{ self.view = [CustomView new]; }
```